# Checkbox not getting checked according to status in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have some values in the following manner:

```
{
    "filter_value": "Pending",
    "filter_level": "DASHBOARD",
    "checked": "false"
}, {
    "filter_value": "Partially Settled",
    "filter_level": "DASHBOARD",
    "checked": "true"
}
```

But the checkbox is getting auto-checked even if the value in checked flag is false. I tried using **[ngModelOptions]** , **[checked]** but none of them is working.

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let TradeType of filterAndSideLinkData.TRADE_TYPE | slice: 4:8; let i = index ">
       <label>
       <input name="tt_{{i}}" class="minimal" [(ngModel)]="TradeType.checked" (ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter(TradeType)" type="checkbox"/>
       <span class="label-text">{{ TradeType.filter_value }}</span>
       </label>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depend to your object must be like that:

```js
{
    "filter_value": "Pending",
    "filter_level": "DASHBOARD",
    "checked": false # boolean not string
}, {
    "filter_value": "Partially Settled",
    "filter_level": "DASHBOARD",
    "checked": true # boolean not string
}
```

Demo:

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let TradeType of TRADE_TYPE ; let i = index ">
    <label>
     <input name="tt_{{i}}" class="minimal" [(ngModel)]
     ="TradeType.checked" checked="TradeType.checked"
     (ngModelChange)="onSelectFilter(TradeType)" type="checkbox"/>
     <span class="label-text">{{ TradeType.filter_value }}</span>
     </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and ts:

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  TRADE_TYPE = [
    {
      filter_value: 'Pending',
      filter_level: 'DASHBOARD',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      filter_value: 'Partially Settled',
      filter_level: 'DASHBOARD',
      checked: true
    }
  ];
  onSelectFilter(TradeType: any) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your JS object the field "checked" is a string and not a boolean, it is converted to true because of javascript implicit coercion.

It becomes a real boolean only after you change its value via the the input checkbox.